# Case-Sensitive SOQL query

Tags: apex, soql

I have the following query:

```
[SELECT Id, Name 
FROM Program__c 
WHERE Name LIKE :**newSearchText** AND (NOT name  like 'BR_%') 
    AND (NOT name  like 'PT_%') AND Portal_Sample_Template_Lookup__c = :tmpId 
LIMIT 2000]
```

And here the `newSearchText` is a text entered by the user.

At the same time, I want to avoid everything record that starts with 'BR_' or 'PT_' to be neglected but if the user enters

eg. 'BRMIG' it doesn't query for the record instead it considers it as 'BR_' and doesnt really considers the '_'. What workaround can I implement for making my result case-sensitive.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to match the summary; case sensitivity is not what is being covered here.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using LIKE, be aware that both "%" and "_" are special characters in this context. This is covered in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm):

> The % wildcard matches zero or more characters.
>
> The _ wildcard matches exactly one character.

To avoid either character from being treated as a wildcard, escape the character. For your example change your query to something like:

```
SELECT Id, Name
  FROM Program__c
  WHERE Name LIKE :newSearchText
    AND (NOT Name LIKE 'BR\_%')
    AND (NOT Name LIKE 'PT\_%')
    AND Portal_Sample_Template_Lookup__c = :tmpId
  LIMIT 2000
```